# Set project variable on runtime

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, circleci-2.0, circleci-workflows

I'm not being able to set an environment project variable on runtime. On my workflow, I got a job that downloads the project and creates a release. I'd like to take the release number and set as an environment variable in a way that could be used later for another job on my workflow.

I've already tried to set the variable using but when the next job on the workflow runs this variable is undefined:

```
echo 'export TAG_VERSION="1.0.0"' >> $BASH_ENV
```

Unfortunately, the job where I want to use this variable is a CircleCI Orbs so there's not much I can change. Here is the link for the Orbs [aws-ecr](https://circleci.com/orbs/registry/orb/circleci/aws-ecr)

This is the job on the workflow

```
- aws-ecr/build_and_push_image:
      tag: ${TAG_VERSION}
      ...
```